# Why doesn't this script set package-archives in Aquamacs?

Tags: package, aquamacs

This is the script I used to initialise packages in emacs:

Inside `~/.emacs.d/init.d`

```el
(load (expand-file-name "package_init.el")
      user-emacs-directory)
```

Inside `~/.emacs.d/package_init.el`

```el
(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line
```

These two scripts work well in emacs 24.

[image]

However it does not work in Aquamacs (`melpa` is not added to the variable `package-archives`)

[image]

I have already verified that aquamacs reads `init.el` when it starts. Here is the start up message in `*message*` buffer

```
Loading prestart plugin files ...
... done.
Wrote /Users/antkong/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Packages/.nosearch
Shell: /bin/zsh
Loading /Users/antkong/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Recent Files.el (source)...done
Cleaning up the recentf list...done (0 removed)
22 environment variables imported from login shell (/bin/zsh).
Loading /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/aquamacs/3.2/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/auctex.el (source)...done
Loading plugins ...
Loading /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/aquamacs/3.2/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/site-start.el (source)...done
... done.
Loading `custom-file' failed.
Loading /Users/antkong/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el (source)...done
Mark set
one-buffer-one-frame-mode disabled.
Mark set [26 times]
Loading /Users/antkong/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/frame-positions.el (source)...done
file-error: (Opening directory no such file or directory /Users/antkong/Library/Logs/CrashReporter)
Mark set [5 times]
Aquamacs is based on GNU Emacs, a part of the GNU/Linux system. It is Free Software: you can improve and redistribute it under the GNU General Public License, version 3 or later. (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, and D. Reitter. No Warranty.
```

Comment: Note that `(load (expand-file-name "package_init.el") user-emacs-directory)` is wrong. You probably meant `(load (expand-file-name "package_init.el" user-emacs-directory))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found out why.

The variable `user-emacs-directory` is set to `"~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Packages/"` by default.

When I add this to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`,

```
(setq user-emacs-directory "~/.emacs.d")
```

the problem is resolved.

Comment: At the bottom of the link to the following thread are a few variables that the user may customize after Aquamacs is built:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16444817/2112489 -- some, however, cannot be changed unless done prior to building it from source.  The thread is about 2 year old and I haven't touched it since, but the variables that are modifiable *probably* haven't changed.

Comment: However there is a reason Aquamacs changed this - with that value some things break - see [Aquamacs code](https://github.com/davidswelt/aquamacs-emacs/blob/aquamacs3/aquamacs/src/site-lisp/macosx/osx_defaults.el) line 197 > ;; Before Aquamcas 3.1, user-emacs-directory was not in "Packages"
  ;; It was moved to the new location in order to avoid having
  ;; emacs-user-directory as part of load-path, which caused (load "tramp") to
  ;; load the wrong file.  GNU Emacs bug #18512